# Looking for the author and title of a story about meeting the stagers and scriptwriters of ones life

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm pretty sure it was a short story about a man deciding to take a shortcut after being stuck in traffic on a highway. By doing this he steps out of his script and meets the stage hands that build the world in the future and tear down the one in the past. There is some humour about the shortage of props and the little time they have to put everything in place. The man wants to go back and they tell him he has to meet the scriptwriters. Maybe they can help him.

Comment: Honourable mention to : [Stranger Than Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_than_Fiction_(2006_film)).

Comment: It sounds like _Yesterday Was Monday_, which would make it a duplicate of [SF Short Story about resetting the world every day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246796/sf-short-story-about-resetting-the-world-every-day). This has been asked about [many, many times already](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+yesterday+was+monday). Please let us know if this is your story so we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: No, it is not Yesterday was Monday. Towards the end the character meets the screenwriters. There rooms and rooms with them all scripting peoples lives.